# Primefaces <p:repeat : Unsupported component-family/renderer-type - No Renderer found for component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

When i use next code in xhtml pages

```
<p:repeat value="#{mybeanView.usernames}" var="username" >
        <br /><h:outputText value="#{username}" />
</p:repeat>
```

it logs next messages (**INFO** and **WARNING**)

can any one explain why ?

and how can i remove (or solve ) these WARNING ?

**[WARNING ]**

```
**Unsupported component-family/renderer-type**: 
org.primefaces.component/org.primefaces.component.UIRepeatRenderer
```

**[INFO]**

```
SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [ElizaTourism]:
            .**No Renderer found for component** {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /admin/tourism/pushNotification.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_9][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView,Id: mainTabView][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab,Id: scheduledNotifications][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: scheduledNotificationsForm][Class: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable,Id: scheduledNotificationsTable][Class: org.primefaces.component.column.Column,Id: j_id_4a][Class: org.primefaces.component.repeat.UIRepeat,Id: j_id_4c]} (component-family=org.primefaces.component, renderer-type=org.primefaces.component.UIRepeatRenderer) created from: xxx.xhtml at line 246 and column 79
```

**[WARNING ]**

```
 **No Renderer found for component** {Component-Path : [Class: 
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: xxx.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_9][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView,Id: mainTabView][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab,Id: scheduledNotifications][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: scheduledNotificationsForm][Class: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable,Id: scheduledNotificationsTable][Class: org.primefaces.component.column.Column,Id: j_id_4a][Class: org.primefaces.component.repeat.UIRepeat,Id: j_id_4c]} (component-family=org.primefaces.component, renderer-type=org.primefaces.component.UIRepeatRenderer) created from: xxx.xhtml at line 246 and column 79
```

Comment: Sure you don't have 2 PF versions in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `<c:foreach>`

The JSTL `<c:forEach>` is a view build time tag (the `<ui:repeat>` is a view render time tag).

See also:
[ui:repeat JSF 2.0 cannot render iterate p:row primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719233/uirepeat-jsf-2-0-cannot-render-iterate-prow-primefaces/)